# Bypass change email screen for Azure AAD B2C Local account sign in

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

When using AD B2C with Local Accounts, the user goes through the following 'flow':

1. Enter email address
2. Send Verification code
3. Verify Verification code

After this, the user has 2 options:

Change email
Continue

In our application we would like to skip this page entirely i.e. after verifying the code proceeding directly to the site

I have seen this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/619255/setting-to-remove-the-change-email-button-in-self but would rather skip the page entirely as opposed to hiding the button

but I haven't been able to figure out anything else, I'm guessing its impossible/not recommended

Comment: We have resolved this with custom JS that presses the button as soon as it detects the page change. The button is hidden with CSS as well.